# How to get latitude/longitude based on entered address in android?

Tags: android

I wanna draw a route on the basis of the entered source & destination address. I need to get lat/log on the basis of address to draw a map in android. So how can i get lat/log on the basis of entered address.

```
 Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder( getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
 try {
     List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Loc",1);
     String add = "";
     if (addresses.size() > 0) 
     {
         add = addresses.get(0);
     }

     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } catch (IOException e) {                
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: I am using google map api to draw a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google Geocoding API to get coordinates for an address: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Comment: Thanx for reply, But using Geocoding, I am getting IOExcetion.

Comment: How are you using it and what's the exact exception. Post source in your original question?

Comment: Ya, But why am i not getting addresses??

Comment: Check out the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String, int, double, double, double, double) It states that null is returned if no coordinates are found. You are searching for "Loc", which most likely returns... well... nothing. Try it with an actual address, such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"

Comment: I have entered actual address still its givig same IOException and message is : "Service is not available".

Comment: The problem is with Android Emulator 2.1 & 2.2. The Above code is working fine in Emulator 2.0.